# Read nested value from json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, nativescript

On the image You can see what I want to read

```
console.log("exact val = " + json._array.loftybot.spells.name)
```

and it gives `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'spells' of undefined]`
You can see in terminal structure of json

How to get into these values?
I want save values from json to array `const json = new ObservableArray`
And then use all of these values in my program

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `json._array[0].loftybot.spells.name`? with an index **0** on your `_array` and go further on nested json. SEE at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics)

Comment: works man thanks a lot

Comment: glad it helps you somehow :)